# jQuery 101 - Change CSS not working with advanced selectors

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors

This is across IE and Firefox.

I have an unordered list of 5 items within li tags.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() //when doc is ready
    {
                $("li:first").css('color', 'red');

    }); 

</script>
```

That does absolutely nothing, however if I leave out the :first part, it makes all li's red, unsure of why since I'm following a tutorial.

Here is the html:

```
<div id="container">
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$(function() //when doc is ready
{
    $("li:first").css('color', 'red');
});//--></script>

<div id="leftcontent">
<center><img src="http://www.dmu.com/5f/images/thiszis.png"></center>
<div id="hoastdears">
<ul>

<li>item1</li>
<li>item2</li>
<li>item3</li>
<li>item4</li>
<li>item5</li>
</ul>
```

With

in the header.

Comment: Your exact code is working for me in this jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/sSbJM/1/  Can you post some of the HTML?  Perhaps the problem is there.

Comment: You need to paste more code. What you have here works just fine.

Comment: Try using $('li').eq(1).css('color', 'red'); ? This should affect the second item. Just in case something else is messing up your first list item

Comment: Ditch the HTML comments in your script unless you're worried about Netscape 1 users.

Comment: Using your supplied HTML, it still works.  http://jsfiddle.net/sSbJM/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("li:first").css('color', 'red');
});
```

Here is a link to the jQuery API http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: There's no difference in functionality between your code and his, they're just synonyms.

Comment: This should be the same thing - the version used by the OP is the shorthand. To be fair I don't know when this shorthand functionality was added so it is worth testing.

Comment: I actually had a case where the shorthand would not work. I never got to the root of the issue though.

Comment: the better shorthand is `jQuery(function($){..code here..});`

Answer (score 1):

Specify a context for your `li:first` selector. Something like:

```
$("li:first", "ul:first").css("color", "red");
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me as is, the problem must be somewhere else:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head><title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$(function() //when doc is ready
{
    $("li:first").css('color', 'red');
});//--></script>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
    <li>First</li>
    <li>Second</li>
    <li>Third</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

**Update:** Find your browser's JavaScript console (in Firefox, it can be found under the *Tools* menu). You might have a syntax error somewhere that's preventing JavaScript code from executing.

Comment: To be clear, copying both of the scripts and adjusting my jquery.js to match yours Alvaro, neither seem to be working, even after clearing cache, etc.